# Custom titlebar - Android crash

Tags: android, crash, titlebar

I'm trying to create a custom titlebar for my application. The problem is that it crashes on startup if I make these changes:

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
```

What could the problem be? I have searched the forum and the net but could not find the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this Call **setContentView(...)** after setting titlebar

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);    
this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: Sadly its still the same instant crash.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. To my mind, you have an error in your XML File

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);      

    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, 
                              R.layout.window_main_title);
 }
```

XML layout.window_main_title :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#323331">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_32"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textHeader"
                android:textSize="15dp"  
                android:textColor="#FEFEFE"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView> 


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work either. Same problem. I will try to get the logcat. I read somewhere that this might not work on Holo?